# Web Services in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib

How to integrate the JSON Web Services/Web Api with our python Program and 
Program should get configuration settings at run time from configuration file

```
 import urllib.request
 a_url = 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
 data = urllib.request.urlopen(a_url).read()
 print(data)
```

I have found this code,regarding my problem.Is this the right way to do?
please help me out of this.

Comment: we don't use urllib, . use [`requests`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/)

Comment: Hi @ShrishtiSoam. Rather ask one question at a time. So ask about how to fetch data from a remote service (and give as much info as possible about this remote web service, e.g. that it returns JSON or maybe what parameters it requires etc.) Then create a separate question about the configuration file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`requests`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/), no sane person uses urllib.

1. Install it:

   ```
   $ pip install requests
   ```
2. Then use it like this:

   ```
   import requests
   a_url = 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
   response = requests.get(a_url)
   response.status_code  # 200
   response.text  # html of the webpage
   # response.json()  # only if the url responds with json data, otherwise it will throw error
   ```